# form with no focus will not move smoothly

Tags: vb.net

I am building a popup keyboard.  I'm using sendkeys, so I don't want the form/keyboard to take focus.  This code prevents that:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.Style = cp.Style Or &H56000000
        Return cp
    End Get
```

However, when I try to move the form/keyboard it doesn't move smoothly.  It will move, but only after you release the mouse.  Is there a way that I can have both, no focus and move smoothly?

Comment: Ugh, a magic number. I have no idea which window styles the hex value `&H56000000` correspond to. This would be *much* easier if you'd declared symbolic constants and ORed them together. Anyway, the only style you really need to be setting here is `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`, which is an *extended* style.

Comment: Cody, do you really think that any part of your response is helpful?  I'm well aware of osk.

Comment: Yes, I think all of it is helpful. Puzzled that you think it isn't. I guess you're mad because you want to do it anyway, even though I told you it's redundant and error-prone? Well, that's your prerogative. I'll never understand why legions of programmers are devoted to reinventing the osk wheel. I also gave advice on how to do it.

Comment: Cody - Many people create programs that are redundant or do not fill a need other than for the heck of it.  We can never learn unless we try.  I have created countless programs that have no purpose.  I have learned tons by doing this.   Stop being pretentious and realize that others have different priorities then you do.  There is the old axiom "If you don't have anything nice to say, don't say anything at all"

Comment: Wow, people really take offense to "Microsoft already wrote this program and using it will save you a lot of work and bugs." I *still* don't understand how that it is *at all* offensive, but yet somehow the comment was flagged as being offensive by multiple people. There's absolutely nothing "pretentious" about it. I wasn't suggesting that you not try and learn, I was suggesting that perhaps there are better ways and things to learn. I don't think saving someone some effort is at all rude. You are obviously free to write whatever code you want. I'm not stopping you.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_MOVING Then
        Dim r As RECT
        r = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(RECT)), RECT)
        Me.Location = New Point(r.Left, r.Top)
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

which then allowed the form to move correctly.

Here's all of the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Const WS_CHILD = &H40000000
Private Const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = &H8000000
Private Const WM_MOVING = &H216

Private Structure RECT
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer
End Structure

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim p As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        p.Style = p.Style Or WS_CHILD
        p.ExStyle = p.ExStyle Or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
        Return p
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_MOVING Then
        Dim r As RECT
        r = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(RECT)), RECT)
        Me.Location = New Point(r.Left, r.Top)
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: There are lots of major problems here. I'm not sure if I should comment at the risk of being labeled "offensive" or "pretentious", but whatever. Your handler for `WM_MOVING` is pointless code, the default window procedure already does that, so you're either redoing work that it already did, introducing a potential bug, or the bug is that it's *not* doing it, and you need to figure out what that is. Programming is not an exercise in hackery. The right way to do it is never just to try stuff until you get the result you want. Maybe that's the difference between my philosophy and other peoples.

Comment: Also, setting the `WS_CHILD` style is a problem. The Form class is designed to be a top-level window, not a child window. If you're going to make it a child, you absolutely have to remove the other top-level styles and modify some of the other behaviors of the Form class's default code. You would be better off just using a UserControl or a Panel for this. But then those don't automatically move when clicked and dragged, so you're back to the scenario in the first comment. The way to fix that is to respond to `WM_NCHITTEST` and return `HTCAPTION` (the part of a window that is draggable).

Comment: If you wanted to be helpful, then show some code!!  I did.  All you have done is babbled.  Why do you even bother commenting?  Is it to show how smart you are?  I'm here to tell you, it's not working!!

Comment: James, showing some code is not the only way to be helpful. I have explained in detail what the problems are with your code and pointed to the ways that they should be fixed. Armed with the information in my comments, you could trivially write the code yourself. Or such is my belief. Maybe I am assuming too much. I'm not interested in proving to anyone how smart I am, I'm interested in sharing knowledge and experience. Apparently you don't find that helpful, which I find very confusing.

Comment: You say above, *"I got this to work and I just don't see all of the bugs you are griping about. Maybe you are remembering the applications you wrote."*, but putting aside the attempt to be offensive, that is missing the point. Sure, you don't see the bugs at first blush because they are subtle. Without a sophisticated understanding of how the Windows programming model works, you might miss them. That's the point of asking on a site where experts share their knowledge. They point out subtle bugs that you might be missing, places where your code *appears* to work, but is dangerously broken.

Comment: You are the first person I have come across here in many years who has been so openly hostile to my suggestions at ways to improve their code, or pointing out lurking bugs. I'm sorry that you don't find this helpful, but I respect your perspective, so I will close this tab and stop commenting. Best wishes to you, and I hope I have not offended you in any way. Such was never my intention.

Comment: Cody, how long have you been doing this? I've been doing this for a few months, and it's a hobby. I've been to no school, I'm learning as I go. So, I'm telling you that your comments have not been helpful, at all. You experts seem to forget that you started somewhere.